# Delete files from directory: memory exhausted

Tags: directory

This question is a logical continuation of [How can I delete all files from a directory when it reports "Argument list too long"](https://serverfault.com/questions/45245/how-can-i-delete-all-files-from-a-directory-when-it-reports-argument-list-too-lo)

I have

```
drwxr-xr-x  2 doreshkin doreshkin 198291456 Apr  6 21:35 session_data
```

I tried

```
find session_data -type f -delete
find session_data -type f | xargs rm -f
find session_data -maxdepth 1 -type f -print0 | xargs -r0 rm -f
```

The result is the same:

```
find: memory exhausted
```

What can I do to remove this directory?

Comment: Are there any reasons why not to use rm -r session_data ?

Comment: @L.R. I couldn't wait to see when it ends. Perhaps I'll do another try.

Comment: Blowing the directory away with `rm -r` is probably the easiest option :)

Comment: I agree with L.R. Your previous post only mentions that you tried rm * -f but not any mention of using rm -r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like a problem with `find`. I noticed a few bug reports of people getting that error with a specific version of GNU findutils.

You can try replacing "find" with "ls" and "grep". Something like this:

```
cd somedir
\ls -f | grep "something" | xargs -d "\n" rm
```

The backslash on `\ls` instead `ls` tells bash to ignore any aliases that will affect your output format. You could also say `/bin/ls` if you forget the backslash trick. The `-f` option tells it to disable sorting (which saves time/memory) and include hidden files. The `-d "\n"` argument to xargs tells it split on newlines instead of spaces. Note that `-d` isn't supported on all versions of xargs, which is a shame.

Note that `ls something*` won't work, since the `something*` is expanded in bash, not by ls, and will result in an "argument list too long" error. Thats why you pipe the result through grep.

Comment: `ls -f` skips sorting the output alphabetically, thus being both quicker and requiring less memory.

Comment: @MattBianco updated

Answer (score 2):

Piping find results through head seems to work for me (I have a similar problem where security camera shots from 6 cameras got uploaded once a minute)

```
find . -type f | head -1000 | xargs rm
```

If it does, loop it:

```
for i in {1..999}
do
   find . -type f | head -1000 | xargs rm
done
```

Replace 999 with how many thousands of files are in there (if you know).

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ls` instead of find (`ls -1 | xargs rm`).

Or

Use a for loop over the output of `ls`

```
#!/bin/sh
for i in `ls -1`; do
  rm $i
done
```

(in both those cases if you're still having trouble the shell may be hitting a memory ceiling: try piping `ls` through `head` to shorten the list)

Or

Write it in perl/C/etc. (iterating over `readdir`'s output & garbage-collecting as you go)

...there are probably more "Or" cases, but these spring immediately to mind.

Comment: See also the answers to your original question (which detail a whole bunch of other great alternatives besides the ones I list above)

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what a recent version of rsync would do with a empty directory as the source and the `--delete` option...

Answer (score 0):

```
find . -type f -print | awk '{ print "rm \"" $1 "\""} | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run rm as part of your find command. No need for pipes/xargs/fancy printing.

find . -exec rm -f {} +

Comment: If the `find` command is running out of memory because of the size of the tree this may not help...