# How to delete files quicker than rm -rf?

Tags: linux, php, command-line-interface, rm, deleting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Millions of files in php’s tmp error - how to delete?](https://serverfault.com/questions/133852/millions-of-files-in-phps-tmp-error-how-to-delete)

Is there any way how to delete folder/files quicker than with command rm -rf?

It seems my disc is filled with bilions of files (sessions of php5) which were not deleted in cron so I need to delete them manually but it takes hours and it is still not helping reducing the amount. Thank you.

My command: `rm -rf /var/lib/php5/*`

Tried also these commands:

```
find /var/lib/php5 -name "sess_*" -exec rm {} \;
```

And

```
perl -e 'chdir "/var/lib/php5/" or die; opendir D, "."; while ($n = readdir D) { unlink $n }'
```

Comment: I added to my first post commands I already tried .. Nothing seems to help ...

Comment: I would bet that the only way would be to store all those files on a different logical drive or partition, and do a quick reformat whenever you needed to clear it.

Comment: Use `find /var/lib/php5 -delete`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php5 should come with a default cron job to remove session files.

In Debian/Ubuntu, it is like the following one (direct copy from Ubuntu 12.04 LTS)

**/etc/cron.d/php5**

```
# /etc/cron.d/php5: crontab fragment for php5
#  This purges session files older than X, where X is defined in seconds
#  as the largest value of session.gc_maxlifetime from all your php.ini
#  files, or 24 minutes if not defined.  See /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime

# Look for and purge old sessions every 30 minutes
09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
```

It run every half an hour, and remove expired session base on **session.gc_maxlifetime** in **php.ini**.

So you should do following:

1. Check if you have the above cron job file. Add it if missing.
2. Check value of **session.gc_maxlifetime** in **/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini**

   Default value of **session.gc_maxlifetime** on Ubuntu is 1440sec = 24min

   ```
   session.gc_maxlifetime = 1440
   ```
3. If the above 2 looks normal, try run the command line in cron job manually. That will print all error on screen.
4. Grep for cron error in /var/log/syslog. See if they are php related.

Regarding the billions session files already exist, you have to delete them manually for now.

**To put the current situation under control**

```
service apache2 stop
mv /var/lib/php5 /var/lib/php5.delete
mkdir /var/lib/php5
chmod 733 /var/lib/php5
chmod o+t /var/lib/php5
service apache2 start
```

Then deleted /var/lib/php5.delete. It may takes hours. At the same time, keep an eye on file number in new */var/lib/php5* directory. If it is increasing in an abnormal way, you properly have problem other than removing files.

**Run cron job command line manually**

Just put the portion after *root* in command prompt, as follow

```
[ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) ! -execdir fuser -s {} 2>/dev/null \; -delete
```

Comment: "Regarding the billions session files already exist, you just have to delete them manually for now." But how that is my question ... My rm -rf command is running like 45 mins and so far deleted 3% o files in this folder so how to do it that is my original question here ...

Comment: BTW my cronjob is like this `09,39 *     * * *     root   [ -x /usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime ] && [ -d /var/lib/php5 ] && find /var/lib/php5/ -depth -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type f -cmin +$(/usr/lib/php5/maxlifetime) -delete`and it is not working ...

Comment: It is not working because it is already out of control. The direct expansion is taking too long and cron job seems to have a max time limit of 1hr. I added a work around in my answer. That will also let you know if session files is increasing in an abnormal way.

Comment: Thank you trying that ... seems normal this folder now ... Thank you. About the cron ... how can I run it manually in command line the line you posted above? To see any errors ...

Comment: @Byakugan I added at the end. Even it gives no error, you still should keep an eye on files number in that dir, maybe for a few days. Also make sure you did the **chmod o+t** for the new folder.

Comment: Now no files are created and sessions (apache php based session and login on page) seems to not working now ... Did I delete anything important in this folder? It is not working even with the chmod option you mentioned ... With chnod 777 it is working now .... 10 files created in 2 mins ... Is that ok?

Comment: @Byakugan Restart apache will fix it. The reason apache fail now, even after chmod, is because it ALREADY open the directory with WRONG permission and staying that way.

Comment: With chnod 777 it is working now .... 10 files created in 2 mins ... Is that ok or is that too many?

Comment: @Byakugan 10 files is VERY normal. Also you should judge that base on your site traffic, number of users. You need historical data. for that.

Comment: Ok seems ok now thank you for everything ... accepting now! One more thing should I leave chod 777 of this new folder or should I use other less dangerous number?

Comment: @Byakugan Try change it back to 755 and +t, that is the original permission. Then restart apache. It should works. If no, **chown :www-data /var/lib/php5**.

Comment: @Byakugan I was wrong, it should be **chmod 733 /var/lib/php5**. I updated my answer. user:group should remain root:root.

Answer (score 3):

The fastest way is probably:

```
cd /var/lib/php5
ls -f | xargs -d "\n" rm
```

Also:

```
cd /var/lib/php5
for i in {1..999}
do
   find . -type f | head -1000 | xargs rm
done
```

And, if you like `perl`:

```
perl -e 'chdir "/var/lib/php5" or die; opendir D, "."; while ($n = readdir D) { unlink $n }'
```

Comment: Already trying these seems quicker but still like 2% in one hour so I will leave it to process through night I think ...